# Google API Ruby Client execute vs Service methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

It seems like there are two ways to use the Google API Client Ruby gem:

- Creating a client and discovered API, and calling `execute`:(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#examples)
- Creating a API Service object and calling specific API methods: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/CalendarV3/CalendarService#list_events-instance_method

The Calendar API documentation examples use the former method, but it seems like the latter method is required to batch requests (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/batch).

Is there a way to batch requests with the former method? Is there a way to reconcile these two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heard back from gem author — the latter is preferred, as it is part of the new syntax being introduced in v0.9 of the gem. Not all the documentation/examples on Google's developer site has been updated at this time, but they have a migration guide:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md